# Error al usar array_chunk en controlador de laravel

Tags: php

Este es el controlador

```
public function index()
    {

     $colla = Colla::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();

      $halved = array_chunk($colla, ceil(count($colla)/2)); 

        return view('ejemplo.vista1', compact('colla', 'halved'));
    }
```

Estoy intentando dividir la matriz en dos partes pero al usar array_chunk para lograrlo me da el siguiente error:
"array_chunk() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que le estas pasando un objeto en el primer argumento.

```
Colla::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get(); 
//Esto te retorna un objeto
```

Puedes usar [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization) para convertirlo en un array. Tu código debería quedar algo así:

```
public function index()
    {

     $colla = Colla::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
     $arrayColla = $colla->toArray();
      $halved = array_chunk($arrayColla , ceil(count($arrayColla)/2)); 

        return view('ejemplo.vista1', compact('colla', 'halved'));
    }
```

Saludos!

Comment: Me ha funcionado correctamente mil gracias